# Java and sudo command execution

Tags: java, mysql, linux, ubuntu, processbuilder

I'm having a challenge with sudo invoked commands using both ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec. I am thinking that ProcessBuilder is overall the better solution but both produce the same result - they execute shell commands fine on Ubuntu, but if I try to do a sudo -i mysql command for example:

```
    public static void runProcess(String[] process) {
        String s = null;
        try { 
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(process).start();
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(s); }
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(s); }
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

These 2 commands work:

```
        String[] cmdArgs0 = { "sudo", "echo", "Done" };
        runProcess(cmdArgs0);

        String[] cmdArgs1 = { "bash", usbDrivePath+"/ASWebUI/Install.sh" };
        runProcess(cmdArgs1);
```

But this does not:

```
        String[] cmdArgs2 = { "sudo", "-i", "mysqldump", "Core", ">", cachePath+"/SQLDumps/Core.sql" };
        runProcess(cmdArgs2);
```

Error:

```
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcessBuilder doesn't allow you to redirect the output using `>` character. Instead you can use [`processBuilder.redirectOutput()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-) method to specify the desired output.

```
File dumpFile = new File("Core.sql");
processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(dumpFile));
```

Or even use `--result-file` option of mysqldump to specify the dump file:

```
mysqldump [options] --result-file=dump.sql
```

Comment: @user3260912 Glad to help! Please check my last edit to the answer, I've changed `Redirect.appendTo(dumpFile)` to `Redirect.to(dumpFile)` since first one corresponds to `>>` instead of `>`.